# Adding items to DetailsView's DropDownList when in edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm still new to ASP.net, but have been looking around to see how to use code behind to add items to a DetailsView's DropDownList when in edit mode.  Everything I've come across hasn't been working, but perhaps I'm applying it incorrectly.

The DetailsView starts in ReadOnly mode.  I read that I have to use FindControl within the DataBound event.  This is what I have so far, but it's not adding any values.

Aspx page

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="315px"
    AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Fields>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-CssClass="button" >
            <ControlStyle CssClass="button"></ControlStyle>
        </asp:CommandField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name"
            SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name"
            SortExpression="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobID" HeaderText="JobID" SortExpression="JobID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SupervisorID" HeaderText="Supervisor"
            SortExpression="SupervisorID" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hire Date" SortExpression="HireDate">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <span class="input-type-text margin-right relative"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HireDate","{0:d}") %>' CssClass="datepicker"></asp:TextBox><img src="images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png" width="16" height="16"></span>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HireDate","{0:d}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HireDate","{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="StatusList"  runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>'>

                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnectionString %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Users] WHERE [ID] = @ID"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Users] ([ClientID], [UserName], [Password], [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [JobID], [SupervisorID], [HireDate], [Status]) VALUES (@ClientID, @UserName, @Password, @FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @JobID, @SupervisorID, @HireDate, @Status)"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [ClientID], [UserName], [Password], [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [JobID], [SupervisorID], [HireDate], [Status] FROM [Users] WHERE [ID] = @ID"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Users] SET [ClientID] = @ClientID, [UserName] = @UserName, [Password] = @Password, [FirstName] = @FirstName, [LastName] = @LastName, [Email] = @Email, [JobID] = @JobID, [SupervisorID] = @SupervisorID, [HireDate] = @HireDate, [Status] = @Status WHERE [ID] = @ID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="curEmp" Type="Int64" />
    </SelectParameters>

    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClientID" Type="Int64" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="JobID" Type="Double" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SupervisorID" Type="Double" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="HireDate" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class EmployeeProfile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
        {

            DropDownList statusList = DetailsView1.FindControl("StatusList") as DropDownList;


            statusList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Test", "Test"));

            statusList.DataBind();

        }

    }


}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm missing here?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DataBound` event of `DetailsView` control.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" 
     OnDataBound="DetailsView1_DataBound" ...>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Check for the `EditMode` in this event using:

`DetailsView.CurrentMode = DetailsViewMode.Edit`

```
protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
          {
            DropDownList statusList = DetailsView1.FindControl("StatusList") as
                                      DropDownList;
                if (statusList != null)
                {
                    statusList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Test", "Test"));
                    statusList.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

**EDIT::**
Now to set the selected value of Dropdownlist in edit mode, use the [**`DataItem`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.dataitem.aspx) property of Details view to get the current item.
The data item is often used to access the field values of the current record directly.

```
 DataRowView row = (DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem
  if (row != null)
   {
     statusList.SelectedIndex =                          
     statusList.Items.IndexOf(ddl.Items.FindByValue(row["Column_Name"].ToString());
   }
```

OR try this one:

```
DataRowView row = (DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem
ListItem liItem = statusList.Items.FindByText(row["Column_Name"].ToString());
if (liItem != null)
  {
    statusList.Items.FindByText(row["Column_Name"].ToString()).Selected = true;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I was missing the OnDataBind in the opening tag for the DetailsView.  I had to take out the SelectedValue in the DropDownList because I was getting errors.  I guess I have to find another way to set the selected value now? This definetly helped to add the items in edit mode, but once I update the selection it doesn't seem to update my choice.  Am I missing something else?

Comment: Edited my answer to set the selected value of dropdownlist in edit mode. Also, if update is not happening, you should post your update code too, any Updated/Updating event of details view etc.. or whatever you are doing to do the update if any, OR better to ask a new question for this

Comment: thanks a lot for the added edit.  I'm assuming the "ddl" in it should be the name of the Dropdownlist correct? In this case "StatusList"? I'll keep working on the update issue and post another question if I need to.  Thanks again for your help!